# Disable button based on variable in other div

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, button

I have an html form where you can select multiple days in the form of a button (in the code, these buttons are the one with the ID **days**). Then, i have a confirm button with the ID **book**, which should be enabled only if at least one of the days button is selected. How can I check this condition considering i have the variable in another div?
Here is the code:

```
<ion-card-content>
<ion-label style="display: block;" class="datepicker_middleTitle"><h3>Pick days</h3></ion-label>
<div class="datepicker_generalDaysContainer" >
    <div class="datepicker_daysOfWeekContainer">
        <div *ngFor="let day of componentData.days" class="datepicker_singleDayWeek">
            <p>{{day.letter}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="datepicker_buttonDaysContainer active">
        <ion-button id="days" style="font-weight: bold;" *ngFor="let day of componentData.days" [class]="day.selected ? 'active' : day.occupied ? 'disabled' : ''" (click)="selectDay(day.number, day.occupied)">{{day.number}}</ion-button>
    </div>
</div>
<ion-button id="book" expand="block" class="btn-big" [disabled]="???" (click)="bookDesk()">BOOK DESK</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

On your days buttons you have `(click)="selectDay(day.number, day.occupied)">{{day.number}}`

So using same method you could store the selected days somewhere, like an array for example.

```js
this.selectedDays = [];
selectDay(number: any, occupied: any) {
  this.selectedDays.push(number);
}
```

I don't see all of your code so be prepared to go add type checkings and refactor where necessary.

We could then check, if we have any dates selected to endable or disable the book buttons.

```html
<ion-button id="book" expand="block" class="btn-big" [disabled]="selectedDays.length == 0" (click)="bookDesk()">BOOK DESK</ion-button>
```